# How to customize a JomSocial template

Tags: templates, jomsocial

I'm a good wordpress user and i wanted to create a community site but found that buddypress needs alot of important functionalities and thats why i switched to jomsocial and joomla.

I have chosen the socialize template here at this link http://socialize.jomsocial.com/ but i can't figure out how to customize it to be just as their demo website.

To be honest i find that wordpress is much more easier.

So please can anyone help me get my first steps with joomla.

Best regards.

Comment: Most of the information you need can be found at http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/Templates_Documentation You will need to log in to access it. They recommend that you download and use their Template Developer Kit to modify templates rather than customizing them on your own.  I believe the Template Developer Kit is free for existing customers. Info about their kit and the download link can be found at http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/Template_Developer_Kit

Answer (score 1):

WP IS easier but less powerfull than Joomla. That's not a secret.

I have never used JomSocial templates, but I know that other template providers always ship QuickStart package with their templates, which looks and functions as template demo site.

Did you get a quickstart with your template purchase?
If you did, just install it whole, instead of plain vanilla Joomla, and you will have exact replica of demo site, which you can customize to your liking.

Otherwise, you will need A LOT OF patience on steep learning curve in order to achieve demo site.
It requires a lot of understanding of Joomla's logic and structure, template's role, components and modules functions, plugin addons...
Something that JSE (Joomla Stack Exchange) is just not made for...

Your best bet is to look for good Joomla tutorials then.
I would recommend looking at [OSTraining Classes](https://www.ostraining.com/classes/) and watch Beginner videos as a good starting point.

Comment: actually my theme doesn't have a quicstart; but i have another one with a quickstart
my question is : if i install the quickstart, will i loose the other themes and plugins that i have and if YES ,,,, is there a way to install the quickstart without loosing them

Comment: Well... it's then much easier to start... Good luck...

Comment: No, there IS NO way of installing quickstart without loosing whole previous site, because quickstart IS A SITE on it's own...

Comment: i think you answerd my reply before i edited it and ask my question ,,,, but anyway thanks for your help @Mikan

Comment: you're quite welcome :-)

Comment: I would reach out to the iJoomla team.  They have pretty good support.